# JS: Function somehow blocks another function

Tags: javascript, function

As the title says - one function somehow blocks another,I got this input:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onMouseOver="onSubmitHover()" onMouseOut="submitFadeOut()" />
```

When I delete onMouseOver function onMouseOut starts to work as I need.

Here are the functions:
onMouseOver:

```
function onSubmitHover()
{
    var emailStatus = document.getElementById("emailstatus").innerHTML;
    var passwordStatus = document.getElementById("passwordstatus").innerHTML;
    var usernameStatus = document.getElementById("usernameStatus").innerHTML = "";
    if((emailStatus == "This email is available")&&(passwordStatus != "Too short")&&(passwordStatus != "")&&(usernameStatus != "This username is available"))
    {
        document.getElementById("submitNote").innerHTML = "Submit data";
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("submitNote").innerHTML = "Please fill in required [*] fields";
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

onMouseOut:

```
function submitFadeOut()
{
    document.getElementById("submitNote").innerHTML = "";
}
```

The problem: When I move my mouse out of the button,I want "submitNote" to be empty, my first function somehow blocks it,I'm not really sure how, or maybe it's some deep mistake for example maybe I'm asking to do two functions at once which is impossible as I know.

Comment: An initial suggestion: Try adding console.log to both functions, and look at the console output to see if one is being called second, or if one is not called at all.

Comment: Your code, as posted, will *always* set "usernameStatus" to the empty string.

Comment: Katana, just tried this out,realised that second function is not getting called,why?Since I got same event for another function and it works with no problems.

Comment: Pointy,the thing is that it's always with string,and never becomes empty.

Comment: Can you post the code that binds the event handlers to the controls?

Comment: Do you realize you are setting the userNameStatus to an empty string and than you are using that as a validation in the next line?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that once the "mouseover" handler has disabled the button, the browser stops generating events for it.

Comment: @JohnWu the event handlers are bound via the attributes in the `<input>` element - it's in the posted code.

Comment: epascarello, thanks, just fixed it,still the main problem haven't been resolved

Comment: Pointy, so,if I would make it always enabled and try to parsing the code in other way,the function would work?

Comment: @Pointy Just tried to do everything without disabling button and it worked,is there any way I could work on disabled button?

Comment: You could use some CSS to alter the look of the button when you want it disabled; maybe add a class to it. Then a "submit" handler for the form could check the state of the button and abort the form submission when it's in the wrong state.

Comment: Perhaps put a div AROUND the button and capture its onMouseOver to clear the submitnote.

Comment: @Donny oh yes, that suggestion from John Wu is easier and simpler than mine :)   Give the `<div>` the style `display: inline-block;` so that it's wrapped around the button. Or use a `<span>`.